# Str object not callable, with Classes

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, subclass

I am learning classes and when I call the class "Animal" it gives me the error: "Str object not callable"

Here is my code:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def name(self):
        print '%s' %(self.name)
rock=Animal("rock")
rock.name()
```

Comment: name is the string attribute  not the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set `self.name = name`, you shadow the method.  Now `rock.name` refers to the string `"rock"`, not the method: `Animal.name`.

One possible fix:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def name(self):
        print '%s' %(self._name)

rock=Animal("rock")
rock.name()
```

But, of course, if you make this change you'll get a surprising result if you do:

```
print rock.name
```

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. Thank you, as I am very new to this. Also, would there ever be a reason to define a class within a class, and would that even work?

Comment: @PatrickCook -- That's an entirely different question.  Classes within classes _do_ work, however I've never found a compelling reason to do it.  Dynamically creating classes also works (and there are a few compelling use-cases there).

Comment: Classes within classes are sometimes useful for naming purposes (that is, the outer class is just a namespace).

Comment: @kindall -- Yeah ... Some people like it.  I've never needed that fine-grained control over my namespacing.  At that point, your module is getting too big and it seems like it might be time to refactor :-), but maybe that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Object.name references the name. So you can either type: rock.name to see the name or you can create a method to extract the name: rock._get_name()

```
    class Animal(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
        def _get_name(self):
            print '%s' %(self.name)
    rock=Animal("rock")
    rock._get_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def my_name(self):
        print '%s' %(self.name)
rock=Animal("rock")
print rock.name
rock.my_name()
```

gives

```
>>>rock
>>>rock
```

**That means:**

When you are trying to call `.name()` it is calling `Animal class` attribute (`name`), which gives `str` .So `str` is not callable.So it should not be called like `rock()`. Thats your error.But class method, here `my_name` is callable, which prints its `attribute` `name`